# Is there a django shorcut for required params in the view

Tags: django, django-views

I am developing a django app with a large amount of views. But every time I write a view I have to cater the possibility of `params` being not provided.. I am writing the same code again and again. I was wondering if there was a django shortcut that could do the job and return a standard error message if a param was not provided.. I want to do something like..

```
@required_params({'get': ['param1', 'param2'], 'post': ['param3', 'param4']})
def my_view(request):
    # Do my stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for this would be to make use of the 'decorator_from_middleware' functionality: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.decorators.decorator_from_middleware

It would allow you to process the request on a per view basis and assert that the parameters from the requet meet your criteria and if not return a standard error response.